# Does PDFsharp with MigraDoc support HTML syntax?

Tags: c#, .net, pdfsharp, migradoc

Does PDFsharp with MigraDoc support HTML syntax?

```
<a> <strong> etc.
```

If yes, how can I implement it on the document?

Answer (score 4):

No, it doesn't support HTML directly.  You have to write a code that reads the HTML and create the PDF using either MigraDoc or PdfSharp.

To create the PDF, you need to use the API, for instance:  `.AddPage(...)`, `.Draw(...)`, `.DrawRectangle(...)`

You have a [full example here](http://www.pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=55&Itemid=63).

You can also use this project to convert HTML to PDF: https://wkhtmltopdf.org/

Comment: I know how to create and poppulate document and didnt want to use another projects for convert

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
para1.AddFormattedText("this text in bold", TextFormat.Bold);
```