# PDFSharp parsing rich text string

Tags: c#, pdfsharp, richtext

I create text blocks using a richtextbox and save them to database. After that i am trying to create a PDF with the strings.

My problem is that i cant find a way to display that formated string in the PDF, it shows every < p > etc. instead of using them correctly. If it is not possible with PDFsharp are there other possibilitys?

```
 // Create a new PDF document
 PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();

 // Create an empty page            
 PdfPage oPage = document.AddPage();

 // Get an XGraphics object for drawing
 XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(oPage);

 //Drawing Images and Rectangles and other things


 //sText is just an example of what my DB string looks like 
 string sText = "<p>Here you can see formattet text<\p> \n 
 always multiple rows and some  g&uuml;  or /r"


 gfx.DrawString(sText, NormalText, XBrushes.Black, new XRect(XUnit.FromCentimeter(3.2), XUnit.FromCentimeter(16.35), oPage.Width, oPage.Height), null);


 // Send PDF to browser
 MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
 document.Save(stream, false);
 Response.Clear();
 Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
 Response.AddHeader("content-length", stream.Length.ToString());
 Response.BinaryWrite(stream.ToArray());
 Response.Flush();
 stream.Close();
 Response.End();
```

Comment: is pdfsharp able to interpret html tags?

Comment: I am not really sure but its the best at the moment for my my situation exept the html strings.

Comment: I think usually you would do it by hand. There are methods in PdfSharp to make a `Section` and add `Paragraphs` to the page and structure it this way. Have a look at [this](http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/invoice-sample.ashx)

Comment: I know that and it would work but the text can change and i don´t want to make multiple PDFs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found an answer. PDFSharp has `XTextFormatter tf = new XTextFormatter(gfx);`
which supports `\n \t \r` so i have do replace my richtextbox witch a normal textbox.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately PDFSharp does not support HTML-Tags:

Have a look at the answers in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20007911/does-pdfsharp-with-migradoc-support-html-syntax). You would need to do it by hand, using the methods that PDFSharp offers.

EDIT: If you need to preserve the HTML-Tags you might use a [Converter](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Convert-from-HTML-to-PDF-09ce2a1d).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564650/convert-html-to-pdf-in-net) is quite an old post concerning this topic.

For PDFSharp the answers in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597103/generate-pdf-based-on-html-code-itextsharp-pdfsharp) might help

Comment: The text will change so by hand is not the perfect solution :/

Comment: I edited my answer, it seems that there are some  workarounds for this problem.

Comment: hm ok looks like i will try to find an other posibility to create my texts

Comment: I personally like PDFSharp and MigraDoc, but never had to deal with HTML yet. good luck! :)